# In PHP, is there a way to loop through a query and organize it into a specific column based on a value?

Tags: php, html, laravel, html-table

I'm using Laravel and attempting to populate a HTML table from a query.  The table from the database has the columns, among others, `id`, `user`, and `shift`.  There is about 100 entries, and the `shift` column will contain the letter `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`.  I want to output it into a single HTML table so that upon looping, the first column in the outputted table will only hold entries with `A` for that value, the second `B`, and so on.

Here is my query:

```
Shift::orderBy('shift', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

This of course sorts it alphabetically and then when I loop using this:

```
      ...
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($shifts as $shift)
          <tr>
              <td>{{ $shift->id }}</td>
            ...
           </tr>
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
  ...
```

Or similar variations, of which I have tried many, it's going to run through all of the entries with `A` and create those cells/rows in the table and then start with `B`.  But by then, because those are already created, the `B` entries start however many of the `A` entries there are down.

I've looped through it and created four separate tables, but I would prefer to have it in one.  I want to export the table with Laravel Excel and if they're separate tables, it just stacks them but I want them side by side.  Anyway, here is what I mean and want (the rows with the letters will be other information in the final table):

[image]

What am I missing?  I feel like I'm not doing something very simple.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You probably need to re-evaluate how you're storing and retrieving your data.  But if you must achieve this goal, it sounds like you need to separate them out into 4 arrays and then join them back together again with each array value containing a nested array with a potential value for A-D.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd have to change something with that.  I would rather not, as this is only for it to display better when exporting it to a spreadsheet and looping through and creating 4 tables is much simpler.  But that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may sort them using [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) which exists for this purpose. `usort()` will sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function.

```
$arr = [
    ['letter'=>'C'],
    ['letter'=>'A'],
    ['letter'=>'B'],
    ['letter'=>'A'],
    ['letter'=>'D'],
];

// Function to sort by provided column name
function cmp($key){
    // Returns comparision function to be used with usort
    return function($a,$b)use($key){
        return strcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}
usort($arr, cmp('letter'));
print_r($arr);
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that most efficient way to achieve this is to make sorting at DB level. For that you should use `orderBy()` method. Also good approach would be having scope for this.

```
public function scopeOrderByShiftsAsc($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('shifts', 'asc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}

// then in your controller
public function index()
{
    $users = \App\User::orderByShiftsAsc()->get();
}
```

You can use this way (`orderBy()`) either in Query builder either in eloquent's method chaining.
[Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes).

Comment: If I just groupBy shift (letters `A` through `D`), it only returns one entry from each letter.  If I groupBy further, it just outputs the result the same as my original query; all the As first, then Bs, Cs, and then Ds.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try now with ordering instead of grouping.

Comment: That's about what my original query was (minus the scope), which I guess I should have posted.  It just orders it alphabetically, so there's about ~20 of each letter one after another.  And they were all imported from a spreadsheet so the created times are the same.  I'd think the only way to achieve this by sorting would be to have it somehow sort by grouping chunks of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`; like taking the first entry from each letter, then just repeating that for each of them.  But I'd imagine that'd have to be done past the DB level, with an array.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. You are mixing about table in HTML and table in DB. Can you post table structure and hard-coded or image of wanted HTML? You don't need to use real data but help us to understand better your request. Follow [these](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) advices to do that.

Comment: Updated the original post.  Sorry for my vagueness and the confusion.

Comment: I am afraid that you misunderstood what I requested. I can hardly believe that there is table in database with 4 fields called `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and every insert in that table is like `INSERT INTO tbl_name (A,B,C, D) VALUES(A,B,C, D),(A,B,C, D),(A,B,C, D);`. I think you forgot to mention something here because table with that structure is meaningless.

Comment: The table structure is roughly:`id`, `user`, and `shift`.  `Shift` will hold the value of `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`.  They are roughly evenly distributed, so about 25 rows will have the value of `A` in that column, 25 will have `B`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
Shift::get()->keyBy('shift')->toArray();
```

You get a structure similar to the following:

```
$data = [
  "A" = [
    ['id' => 1, 'shift' => 'A'],
    ...
  ],
  "B" = [
    ['id' => 2, 'shift' => 'B'],
    ...
  ],
  ...
]
```

Next, you can iterate over the largest letter and create the desired output structure:

```
$letters = array_keys($data)
$maxLength = 0
foreach($letters as $letter) {
  $len = count($data[$letter]);
  if ($len > $maxLength) $maxLength = $len;
}
$output = []
for($i = 0; $i < $maxLength: $i++) {
   $newRow = [];
   foreach($letters as $letter) {
     if (isset($data[$letter][$i])) {
       $newRow[$letter] = $data[$letter][$i]['id'];
     } else {
       $newRow[$letter] = '';
     }
   }
   $output[] = $newRow;
}
```

Then you can just pass the output to the blade file and create the table as:

```
@foreach ($output as $row)
      <tr>
          <td>{{ $row['A'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row['B'] }}</td>
          ...
       </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that query only result in four of the entries being in that array (1 from each letter, as that is the key)?  There is ~25 rows for each letter that I would need to collect and then loop through.

Comment: No, this should get everything.